# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.io.Files.newReaderSupplier(Ljava/io/File;Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;)

Tags: java, guava

I am getting the following exception from one private library:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.io.Files.newReaderSupplier(Ljava/io/File;Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;)Lcom/google/common/io/InputSupplier;
```

After researching it seems the issue is with a google guava jar.
I am using google guava jar version 17.0 and tried changing the version also.But was not able to figure out the specific jar version that will resolve the issue.

Please help.

Comment: Do you use Maven to assembly your project?

Comment: yes.maven build is successful.Exception is coming during weblogic 12.2.1.2 deploy

Comment: Actually, Guava 17.0 [still has such method](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.guava/guava/17.0/com/google/common/io/Files.java#Files.newReaderSupplier%28java.io.File%2Cjava.nio.charset.Charset%29), it's marked as deprecated, but still here. Run `mvn dependency:tree` and analyze output. I guess you're overriding dependency in one of your poms. Also try to force update `mvn clean package -U`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with Weblogic 12c which adds Guava 17.0 jar internally.So it ignores the Guava jar in the maven pom.xml .

To solved this issue add weblogic.xml in the application/war and mention the packages that needs to be excluded.